# Find the angle value from a width and a height?

Tags: geometry

I'm making a program where a user can add a radius to the edge of a rectangle by dragging a handle in the corner and moving it at an angle to adjust the value.

I am tracking the cursor when the handle is clicked, I am evaluating the position relative to the edge.

The cursor only prints x and y coordinates from my knowledge. With those coordinates, I want to move the handle at an angle and set the radius value to match that value.

An example would be that the user selects the left handle and moves the mouse 30px on the x-axis (relative to the rectangles' top left edge) and 20px on the y axis. x = 30, y = 20 what is the angle value and what should the radius value be?

is it as simple as x / y?

[image]

Comment: I think you should use the tan function to compute the angle: https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling I needed sin, cos, and or tan. I dont know enough about them though. I will do some research.

Comment: The tan of your angle is y/x. So the angle can be found by arctan(y/x).

Comment: Once I have the angle, do you know how it can be made possible to increment the value by 1 at a time as the arc grows? I think its called normalization?

Comment: This is what I did and it's close `Math.round(Math.atan2(y, x) * 100);`

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Once you have the angle you can increment it. The new x and y will be: x=cos(angle) and y=sin(angle). If you are using Java then the angle must be in radians (not degrees!)

Comment: The radius is computed based on Pythagorean theorem. The increments are than increment by Cos to x direction and Sin for y direction.